# HTML Round Button Resizing

Tags: html, css

I am working on a back button for my website, I am not too sure how to make the button smaller. I tried adjusting the font size applying negative padding, etc. But to no avail I was able to get the button size to shrink while maintaining its round shape. Below is the CSS which I had applied on my button.

```
.fa-arrow-left{
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius : 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image]

I am looking to strink the button to about 50% of this current size while maintaining the round shape as well. Appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Start by reducing the explicitly set `width` and `height` of `100px` maybe …? (And if that doesn’t achieve what you are after, then give us a proper [mre] of your issue first of all.)

Comment: why can't you simple decrease with `width` & `height`?

Comment: Hi @Vsync and CBroe, tried that already, but i will lose the circle shape of my button, i tried values starting from 1 px  for this. Only 100 px is able to give me that round shape which I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detail you are giving is not really satisfactory. Try changing the `width` and `height` properties to lower values. If that doesn't help, you can use `transform: scale(.5);` but that is more than suboptimal.

If you are using font-awesome (as the `fa`-prefix suggests), changing the `font-size` should do the trick.

Comment: Hi @Bastion Springer, "transform: scale(.5)", did the trick ! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Also i do apologies for giving such a vague description here, am new to stackoverlflow and was just starting out with HTML and CSS.

Comment: yeah, obviously it does the trick. It's just janky af once you start adding content next to or beneath this arrow. That's why I said it's more than suboptimal. CSS `transform` does not alter the document flow in any way, thus the content around this arrow will flow as if the arrow had twice the size of the visible size. But hey, as long as you can live with that it should be fine. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
```

As height and width are usually the parameters determining the size of your html elements.

You already set border radius to

```
border-radius : 50%;
```

So this will be applied no matter the size of your element.

Comment: Hi @Lukas A, i tried reducing height and width of the button, but was not able to retain the circular form of the button. Bastian Springer's suggestion for "transform: scale(.5)" did the trick for me.